# Filtering checkboxes checked in Angular

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have a list of users whose presence is marked with a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-checked="{{user.presence}}">
```

I would like to create a way to display in the list the users that are with the checkbox checked, selecting the "present" option in the select and the users that are with the checkbox unchecked by selecting the "absent" option in the select.

How can I do this?

See my code here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPzNEb

Comment: Post your code and we can get you started.

Comment: Hi @cChacon! Here is my code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPzNEb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a number of issues with your code. First, you weren't holding the select value anywhere, so I added this to the model. I removed 'default' from the default option to make checking for this cleaner. I created a filter and used this to filter your list. See the updated codepen below.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dZpLbb

html

```
<select ng-model="selectOption">
    <option value="" selected>
        Select an option
    </option>
    <option value="present">
        Present
    </option>
    <option value="absent">
        Absent
    </option>
</select>
....
<tr data-ng-repeat="user in id | filterByPresence:selectOption">
    ....
</tr>
```

app.js

```
app.filter('filterByPresence', function (){
  return function( users, selectOption ) {
      console.log('filterByPresence', selectOption);
      var filtered = [];
      angular.forEach(users, function(user) {
        if (!selectOption) {
          filtered.push(user);
        } else if (selectOption == 'present' && user.presence) {
          filtered.push(user);
        } else if (selectOption == 'absent' && !user.presence) {
          filtered.push(user);
        }
      });

      return filtered;
    };
})
```